# How to make complex query with searchkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I need to make a query that access association to check if current_user is able to do that search. I don't know how to do it directly from searchkick query, so I do the search and then I iterate over all items and remove the ones current_user can't access, but this is not efficient. Also, this search is paginated.

The object is called `HeroPage`. It has an polymorchic attribute called `hero_object`, which can be a `User` or a `Organization`.

The code I'm doing right now:

```
@hero_pages_search = HeroPage.search params[:q], fields: [ :name, :first_name, :last_name ], match: :word_start
```

After this, I iterate over all object to check if current_user is able to access it:

```
@hero_pages = []
@hero_pages_search.each do |hp|
  @hero_pages.push(hp) if (hp.hero_object_type == 'User' && can_add_user(hp))
  @hero_pages.push(hp) if (hp.hero_object_type == 'Organization' && can_add_org(hp))
end
```

I think `can_add_user` and `can_add_org` doesn't matter that much, but here is one of them:

```
def can_add_user(hp)
  user = hp.hero_object
  (user.who_can_find_and_fan == 'anyone_find_fan') || user.my_network_user_ids.include?(current_user.id)
end
```

How can I do this more efficiently? Since I need to paginate it, I don't know how to do this properly. Can I do all this only with a SearchKick query?
Maybe get `@hero_pages_search` with size like `per_page`*4? So I would be able to filter later on iteration.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to index either the authorized or unauthorized user ids   and/or organization ids on the HeroPage index and filter by those fields.

Example query:

```
HeroPage.search(
 params[:q],
 fields: [ :name, :first_name, :last_name ],
 match: :word_start,
 where: { authorized_user_ids: user_id }
)
```